# Custom validation bootstrap script

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap form. I want to do validation on this form with pattern for example only alphabet regex for name field
My form validation does not work. where is problem?

```js
const nameinp = document.getElementById('nameinp');
let isPasswordValid = false;
let en = nameinp.value;
const ptern = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
isPasswordValid = ptern.test(en);
(() => {
  'use strict'
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');

  Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {

      if (!form.checkValidity() || !isPasswordValid) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }

      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()
```

```html
<form id="Oform" action="" class="form-control needs-validation" novalidate>
  <label for=" OName">name</label>
  <input required id="nameinp" type="text" name="nameinp" id="OName" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group form-control">
    <label class="col-sm-12" for="IPrange"> family</label>

    <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="IPrange">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="submitbtn" type="submit">submit </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the validation into the submit event.

Where you have it now it only tests the input when the form loads, not when it is filled and submitted

Also no need to do Array from

Lastly your test was testing the existence of ONE a-zA-Z

```js
(() => {
  'use strict'
  document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
  .forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      const nameinp = document.getElementById('nameinp');
      let isPasswordValid = false;
      let en = nameinp.value.trim();
      const ptern = /^[A-Za-z]*$/;
      isPasswordValid = ptern.test(en);
      console.log( isPasswordValid)
      if (!form.checkValidity() || !isPasswordValid) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
        console.log('not valid')
      }
      // else // I would expect an else here 
      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()
```

```html
<form id="Oform" action="" class="form-control needs-validation" novalidate>
  <label for=" OName">name</label>
  <input required id="nameinp" type="text" name="nameinp" id="OName" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group form-control">
    <label class="col-sm-12" for="IPrange"> family</label>

    <input required class="form-control" type="number" max="254" min="1" name="" id="IPrange">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="submitbtn" type="submit">submit </button>
</form>
```

And if there is only one form then even less reason

```js
(() => {
  'use strict'
  document.querySelector('.needs-validation')
    .addEventListener('submit', event => {
      const form = event.target;
      form.classList.remove('was-validated')
      form.classList.remove('invalid')
      const nameinp = document.getElementById('nameinp');
      let isPasswordValid = false;
      let en = nameinp.value.trim();
      const ptern = /^[A-Za-z]*$/;
      isPasswordValid = ptern.test(en);
      if (!form.checkValidity() || !isPasswordValid) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
        form.classList.add('invalid')
      }
      else {
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }
    })
})()
```

```css
.invalid { border: 1px solid red; }
.was-validated { border: 1px solid green; }
```

```html
<form id="Oform" action="" class="form-control needs-validation" novalidate>
  <label for=" OName">name</label>
  <input required id="nameinp" type="text" name="nameinp" id="OName" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group form-control">
    <label class="col-sm-12" for="IPrange"> family</label>

    <input required class="form-control" type="number" max="254" min="1" name="" id="IPrange">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="submitbtn" type="submit">submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: but by name contain number form submitted !!

Comment: Fixed. Your regex was not complete

Comment: thanks but name filed no red border

Comment: What red border? You have novalidate

Comment: i want when name filed contain numeric character, border of name field change to red. (either of required and alphabet character validation)

Comment: That was not in the original question

Comment: I added some css